# Docusign Elastic template with signature

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

In an docusign embedded Eleastic Template, is there a way to replace the checkbox with a customer signature like it's done when signing by email or a way to ask the signer to select a predefined signature image when the embedded Eleastic Template  is presented for signature

I tried to use data fields but no signature data type available

Answer (score 0):

Elastic templates are not intended to capture agreements with signatures. If you want to capture a signature you would probably want to use [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/) instead. Elastic templates work for use cases such as terms and conditions where the user consents to terms with a single click.